# need help on debug c# XML-parsing

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

my c# code makes VisualStudio (2013) not respond while using the whole XMLfile (189 descriptors having 64 features each), but on a small amount works well

```
        Matrix<float> ObjectDescriptors = new Matrix<float>(200, 64); 
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("descriptors.xml");
        int i = -1;
        int ii = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.Name == "feature" && ii < 64)
            {                   
                ObjectDescriptors[i, ii] = reader.ReadElementContentAsFloat();

                ii++;
                if (ii == 64) ii = 0;
            }
            else if (reader.Name == "descriptor") i++;
        }
```

The XML data is clean. Has anyone ideas why the time increases non linearly while the samples number increases? Or the problem is elsewhere?

Thank you!

Comment: What library are you using for Matric?  Right click on Matrix and select "go to definition".

Comment: i use Emgu.CV , everything works if splitting the XML file in 3 parts. Every part is processed normally, but using the whole XML makes it not responding (without error)

Comment: Please, show xml file structure. Note: you don't need this statement: `&& ii < 64`

Comment: Alexander Petrov, thank you! You are definitely right, this check on the number 64 is explicit and useless! the XML looks like: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <descriptor>
    <feature>5.12</feature>
    <feature>0.0002827647</feature> .....
    <feature>0.0147277</feature>
    <feature>0.00037847</feature>
 </descriptor>
</root>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any exception handling?

Expression: `else if (reader.Name == "descriptor") i++;` must lead to increment `i` as well start element `descriptor`, as end element.

In my test code, this leads to IndexOutOfRangeException.
Perhaps your code hangs on exception handling?

Try this: `else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "descriptor") i++;`

Moreover, I can offer two more ways.

Use [NameTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.nametable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This may improve performance. However, the number of nodes 189 * 64 is not very large. The difference is almost negligible.

```
NameTable nt = new NameTable();
object feature = nt.Add("feature");
object descriptor = nt.Add("descriptor");

var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.NameTable = nt;

using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("descriptors.xml", settings))
{
    int i = -1;
    int ii = 0;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(feature, reader.Name))
        {
            ObjectDescriptors[i, ii] = reader.ReadElementContentAsFloat();
            ii++;
            if (ii == 64) ii = 0;
        }
        else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && object.ReferenceEquals(descriptor, reader.Name)) i++;
    }
}
```

Another way:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("descriptors.xml"))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.ReadToFollowing("descriptor"))
        {
            int i = -1;
            do
            {
                i++;
                if (reader.ReadToFollowing("feature"))
                {
                    int ii = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        ObjectDescriptors[i, ii] = reader.ReadElementContentAsFloat();
                        ii++;
                    } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("feature"));
                }
            } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("descriptor"));
        }
    }
}
```

I used your ugly indexing starting on -1.

Also note that XmlTextReader is not recommended long ago. Create reader using XmlReader.Create.

PS: что ж ты на русском не спросил? пришлось долго словарь и переводчик мучить.

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed answer, not only showing the right way to make it but also providing useful tips!  Большое спасибо за Ваш развернутый ответ и полезные дополнительные рекомендации! Думал, что задавать вопросы на родном языке на этом сайте запрещено т.к. сужает число людей, способных дать ответ.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the XML parser, you may try another approach such as

```
float[,] data = new Float[200,64];
int row = 0, col = 0;
var tags = XElement.Parse(file).XPathSelectElements("descriptor|feature");

foreach(var node in tags)
{
   if (node.Name == "descriptor")
   { row++; col = 0; }
   else if (node.Name == "feature")
   { data[row, col++] = (float)node; }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I checked out the approach you suggest. Seem like it is building a tree model. I don't need one, just need to fill a Matrix.

Comment: I have updated the code to show how you can use it to get the data you want.
PS: I did not test this code, I just wrote it here in the web browser so apologizes for potential small syntax issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for the provided code! I have decided to switch to LINQ as I can't solve the issue by current means. I will check your code! Thank you!